# This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: block-scoped function declaration

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, google-tag-manager, ecmascript-5

I have two banners that needs to be displayed when one of the divs exist on my HTML, I've made this script and it works perfectly. The problem is that I'm using GTM and it gives this error: "This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: block-scoped function declaration." How can I transform my function to a code that GTM accepts it?

```js
    var element = document.getElementById('chamaBannerVB')
var elementZC = document.getElementById('chamaBannerZC')
    if (element !== null) {
        function appendHtmlVB() {
            var divVB = document.getElementById("chamaBannerVB");
            divVB.innerHTML += '<a href="https://vidabalanceada.com.br/facaparte?mktcode=IDSTCS" target="_blank"><img class="bannerEbookVB" src="https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/mobile_banner_ebook_vb_LS_03-2023.png" alt="Banner Mobile" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;"></a>';
            var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
            styleSheet.innerText = styles
            document.querySelector(".bannerEbookVB").appendChild(styleSheet);
        }       
        window.onload = appendHtmlVB;
        var styles = "@media (min-width: 768px) {" + ".bannerEbookVB {" + "content: url(https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/banner_ebook_vb_LS_03-2023.png); max-width: 800px!important;" +"}}"

    } else {
        function appendHtml() {
            var div = document.getElementById("chamaBannerZC");
            div.innerHTML += '<a href="https://zenconecta.com.br/facaparte?mktcode=IZSTCS" target="_blank"><img class="bannerEbook" src="https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/mobile_banner_ebook_zc_LS_03-2023.png" alt="Banner Mobile" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;"></a>';
            var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
            styleSheet.innerText = styles
            document.querySelector(".bannerEbook").appendChild(styleSheet);
        }       
        window.onload = appendHtml;
        var styles = "@media (min-width: 768px) {" + ".bannerEbook {" + "content: url(https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/banner_ebook_zc_LS_03-2023.png); max-width: 800px!important;" +"}}"
    }
```

```html
<!-- <div id="chamaBannerVB"  style="text-align: center; display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 16px 0; "></div> -->

<div id="chamaBannerZC"  style="text-align: center; display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 16px 0; "></div>
```

Comment: Declare the functions outside the `if` blocks. They have different names anyway, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Pointy How should I declare it?

Comment: Move them outside the `if` blocks.

Comment: @Pointy sorry I don't get it. Can you write? I should remove the if blocks? But that's how I see if the div exists

Comment: It's extremely simple: **move the function declarations**.  Copy and paste, or however your text editor works. Move them from *inside* the blocks to before the `if` statement.

Comment: And not "remove", "move".  Like, if I said "move your car to the other side of the street" I would not mean "make your car disappear".

Comment: @Pointy Oh i see now, it worked and there's no more errors in GTM. Thank you so much

Comment: This is easy enough to fix with “readable” JavaScript code, but if all you have is an already minified block of code, it is not necessarily super easy to restructure without risking that anything breaks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either global functions (declared in the top scope)

```
function appendHtmlVB() {
    var divVB = document.getElementById("chamaBannerVB");
    divVB.innerHTML += '<a href="https://vidabalanceada.com.br/facaparte?mktcode=IDSTCS" target="_blank"><img class="bannerEbookVB" src="https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/mobile_banner_ebook_vb_LS_03-2023.png" alt="Banner Mobile" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;"></a>';
    var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
    styleSheet.innerText = styles
    document.querySelector(".bannerEbookVB").appendChild(styleSheet);
}
function appendHtml() {
    var div = document.getElementById("chamaBannerZC");
    div.innerHTML += '<a href="https://zenconecta.com.br/facaparte?mktcode=IZSTCS" target="_blank"><img class="bannerEbook" src="https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/mobile_banner_ebook_zc_LS_03-2023.png" alt="Banner Mobile" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;"></a>';
    var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
    styleSheet.innerText = styles
    document.querySelector(".bannerEbook").appendChild(styleSheet);
}

var element = document.getElementById('chamaBannerVB')
var elementZC = document.getElementById('chamaBannerZC')
if (element !== null) {
    window.onload = appendHtmlVB;
    var styles = "@media (min-width: 768px) {" + ".bannerEbookVB {" + "content: url(https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/banner_ebook_vb_LS_03-2023.png); max-width: 800px!important;" +"}}"

} else {
    window.onload = appendHtml;
    var styles = "@media (min-width: 768px) {" + ".bannerEbook {" + "content: url(https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/banner_ebook_zc_LS_03-2023.png); max-width: 800px!important;" +"}}"
}
```

or just don't use function declarations at all, directly assigning a function expression to the event handler attribute:

```
var element = document.getElementById('chamaBannerVB')
var elementZC = document.getElementById('chamaBannerZC')
if (element !== null) {
    window.onload = function appendHtmlVB() {
        var divVB = document.getElementById("chamaBannerVB");
        divVB.innerHTML += '<a href="https://vidabalanceada.com.br/facaparte?mktcode=IDSTCS" target="_blank"><img class="bannerEbookVB" src="https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/mobile_banner_ebook_vb_LS_03-2023.png" alt="Banner Mobile" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;"></a>';
        var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
        styleSheet.innerText = styles
        document.querySelector(".bannerEbookVB").appendChild(styleSheet);
    };
    var styles = "@media (min-width: 768px) {" + ".bannerEbookVB {" + "content: url(https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/banner_ebook_vb_LS_03-2023.png); max-width: 800px!important;" +"}}"

} else {
    window.onload = function appendHtml() {
        var div = document.getElementById("chamaBannerZC");
        div.innerHTML += '<a href="https://zenconecta.com.br/facaparte?mktcode=IZSTCS" target="_blank"><img class="bannerEbook" src="https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/mobile_banner_ebook_zc_LS_03-2023.png" alt="Banner Mobile" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;"></a>';
        var styleSheet = document.createElement("style")
        styleSheet.innerText = styles
        document.querySelector(".bannerEbook").appendChild(styleSheet);
    };
    var styles = "@media (min-width: 768px) {" + ".bannerEbook {" + "content: url(https://img.selecoesbrasil.com.br/banner_ebook/banner_ebook_zc_LS_03-2023.png); max-width: 800px!important;" +"}}"
}
```